# Sharepoint list content from parent site to subsite

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a list with multiple records in it. I want to filter some records from the list and display it on subsite web page. I goggled it and I found out that there is no direct way to use the list from parent site into subsite. I am using Sharepoint 2013 and I have full control access to site.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you're correct--there doesn't seem to be a way to pull list items from a parent site to a subsite, at least not in the sense that you most likely want. This is a shot in the dark, but if you're looking to pull in static list items, such as street suffixes or product names, you can create a content type in your parent site that will pass down values you define in a choice field. If you really need dynamic linkage, give this a look: http://www.boostsolutions.com/cascaded-lookup.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to display a SharePoint list from Parent site in a subsite:

- Using Data View Web Part.
- Using Content Query Web Part.

[image]

**Check the details steps at**

- [How to display a sharepoint list from parent site in subsite?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)
- [SP 2016 - Display list from Parent site in sub-site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226651/sp-2016-display-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site/226657#226657)